# MySQL escape string help

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a pretty large insert statement something like

```
INSERT INTO multimedia (filename, regex, flag) VALUES (('adsfavr.jpg', '<div id="title">', 0), (...), (...));
```

How do I prepare the query for MySQL.It's too long to do it manually. It includes double quotes so I can't use the php function mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: If you can use mysql_real_escape_string, what is your problem exaclty? You should use mysql_real_escape_string on every variable before using them in a query.

Comment: The query was in a comma separated file, i can't use mysql_real_escape_string because of quotes in regexes

Comment: Hi gAMBOOKa. You probably wanted to write "can't use" instead of "can use" in your original post, didn't you?

Comment: That depends on where the data came from and what structure it is before you start to generate the insert statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to insert all records with a single statement? You could use a prepared statement:
    INSERT INTO multimedia (filename, regex, flag) VALUES (?, ?, ?);

and a for-loop to insert the records one by one.

I'm not a PHP programmer, but the code could look like this (parts taken from http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO multimedia (filename, regex, flag) VALUES (:filename, :regex, :flag)");
$stmt->bindParam(':filename', $filename);
$stmt->bindParam(':regex', $regex);
$stmt->bindParam(':flag', $flag);

for ( $i = 1; $i <= ...; $i++) {
    $filename = ...
    $regex = ...
    $flag = ...

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Using a prepared statement, the DBMS only compiles the SQL once, as it would with your SQL statement. To get sure that either all or no records are inserted (if you need such an assertion anyway), use a transaction.

Further, this would also solve your escaping problem, since you don't need to put the values in a string. The string for a prepared statement only defines the SQL "template".

Answer (score 0):

if your data stored in a comma separated file, you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` query

A sample of this data could help.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this way to execute multiple inserts in a single query...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, age)
  VALUES
  ('Helen', 24),
  ('Katrina', 21),
  ('Samia', 22)";

mysql_query( $sql);
```

Comment: Hi PHP-Prabhu. The reasons I downvoted this are: 1) This is actually what gAMBOOKa wanted to do but asked how; 2) It is IMHO a bad idea to use multiple (...) expressions to dynamically insert multiple records.